# Sq-lite Android Cursor does not work in specific column

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cursor

I have one code that i want to export one value increment by one and store it back, i tried the way i do in every other function but for this i don't get something back with the cursor, i don't know if it's my SQL or something on the code, everything looks fine to me can't find the mistake.

All i know is that parousies_max keeps the value it has before the cursor.getString but it gets normally the +1

The Database is like this with only one input to check it for now

```
TABLE_NAME2=Mathimata_table
ID_MATHIMA:001 - ONOMA_MATHIMA:Pro1 - EXAMINO_MATHIMA:1 - PAROUSIES_MAX:0 - KLEIDI:4888
```

And my code is this :

```
final String SQL_EXAGOGH_PAROUSIES_MAX = final String SQL_EXAGOGH_PAROUSIES_MAX = 
"SELECT "+DatabaseHelper.Col_PAROUSIES_MAX+" 
 FROM "+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME2+" 
 WHERE "+DatabaseHelper.Col_ID_MATHIMA+" = "+id_math;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQL_EXAGOGH_PAROUSIES_MAX,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            parousies_max = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PAROUSIES_MAX"));
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
efedriko=Integer.parseInt(parousies_max);
efedriko=efedriko+1;
parousies_max=Integer.toString(efedriko);

  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("PAROUSIES_MAX",parousies_max);
        contentValues.put(Col_KLEIDI,kleidi );
        db.update(TABLE_NAME2, contentValues,"ID_MATHIMA = ?",new String[] {id_math});
```

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work? What happens exactly with this column?

Comment: nothing, when i run this code i just don't get anything back from the cursor to the parousies_max that normally parousies_max should get cursors return 0,1,2,3 or whatever the database has,but keeps the value it had when it was first initialized so it does not get anything from the database

Answer (score 0):

As you said cursor is not having any value with the column name  `DatabaseHelper.Col_PAROUSIES_MAX`
this will happen only when there is no matching record(i.e. `DatabaseHelper.Col_ID_MATHIMA+" = "+id_math` this condition is not satisfying) has found in the table or no record in the table.

so my suggesstion is check the value of the variable `id_math` and format it so it will match the format as you are storing the record in table,

one more thing if `DatabaseHelper.Col_ID_MATHIMA`  is having `datatype` as `text` ,as per the data you have given (`ID_MATHIMA:001`) and while updating the record you are pass as String , then use  quote before and after `id_math` so your final query will be like this

```
final String SQL_EXAGOGH_PAROUSIES_MAX = final String SQL_EXAGOGH_PAROUSIES_MAX = 
    "SELECT "+DatabaseHelper.Col_PAROUSIES_MAX+" 
     FROM "+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME2+" 
     WHERE "+DatabaseHelper.Col_ID_MATHIMA+"='"+id_math+"'";

     SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQL_EXAGOGH_PAROUSIES_MAX,null);
```

// if only one record will be the  outcome of this query then use below code and delete the while loop

```
             if(cursor != null)
                {
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        parousies_max = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PAROUSIES_MAX"));
                    }
                    else{
                     //also handle the case of no record found in here
                       //set as parousies_max ="0" ;
                    }
                }
```

///else think on your logic again because if multiple records are there as outcome of this query then while loop is ok but in that case also you will always get last record as per your logic.
if that is your need then also don't use while loop for such case use below code

```
 if(cursor != null){
   if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
       parousies_max = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PAROUSIES_MAX"));
     }
     else{
           //also handle the case of no record found in here
           //set as parousies_max ="0" ; or 

    }
 } 
 cursor.close();
 efedriko=Integer.parseInt(parousies_max);
    efedriko=efedriko+1;
    parousies_max=Integer.toString(efedriko);

  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("PAROUSIES_MAX",parousies_max);
        contentValues.put(Col_KLEIDI,kleidi );
        db.update(TABLE_NAME2, contentValues,"ID_MATHIMA = ?",new String[] {id_math});
```